# How to Fill Nulls for Lead window using multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have OppTable

---

```
   ID           actualclosedate    status
--------------------------------------
    1            10-March    Won  
    2            11-June     Lost
    3            13-July     Open
```

I have stage change

```
--------------------------------------
   ID         stage       createdon   
--------------------------------------
    1         Propsect    1-Jan        
    1         Qualify     15-Jan       
    1         Develop     25-Jan       
    2         Qualify     9-Feb       
    2         Develop     7-March     
    3         Prospect    9-April 
    3         Prospect    9-April
```

How Can I fill the NULL values in the new column generated based on multiple criteria.
Ex: if Opp is WON/LOST put close date
    if Opp is Open put today date

Expected results:

```
--------------------------------------
   OppID      Stage       createdon   newcolumn 
--------------------------------------
    1         Propsect    1-Jan        15-Jan
    1         Qualify     15-Jan       25-Jan 
    1         Develop     25-Jan       10-March ---(closedate for Wonn Opp1)
    2         Qualify     9-Feb        7-March
    2         Develop     7-March      11-june  ---(closedate for lost Opp2)
    3         Prospect    9-April      10-April
    3         Qualify     10-April     4/2/2017----(todaydate for Open Opp3)
```

Using this Query, will get me actual close date for open but I want Today Date

```
Select *
      ,NewColumn = COALESCE(Lead(A.createdon) over (Partition By A.ID Order By A.CreatedOn),B.actualclosedate)

 From  stagechange A
 Join  OppTable B on A.ID=B.ID
```

Comment: This query does not compile, I am afraid. What is `B.actualclosedate`?

Comment: If you want today for an 'Open'  status you can use `CASE WHEN status = 'Open' THEN Current_Date ELSE B.actualclosedate END)` instead of `B.actualclosedate` within `COALESCE`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT a.ID, a.Stage, a.CreatedOn, b.CloseDate, b.Status,
           LEAD(a.CreatedOn) OVER (PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY a.CreatedOn) ld,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY a.CreatedOn DESC) rn,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY a.CreatedOn DESC) dr
    FROM stagechange a
    INNER JOIN OppTable b
        ON a.ID = b.ID
)
SELECT t.ID, t.Stage, t.CreatedOn,
       CASE WHEN (t.rn <> 1 OR t.rn = t.dr) AND t.ld IS NOT NULL THEN t.ld
            WHEN t.Status <> 'Open' THEN t.CloseDate
            ELSE GETDATE()
        END AS newcolumn
FROM cte t
ORDER BY t.ID, t.CreatedOn;
```

I found that using both `ROW_NUMBER()` and `DENSE_RANK()` was necessary to handle the edge case of where a given `ID` can have multiple equivalent closing dates.  In this case, we need some way of identifying which one is the oldest.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester